# How to remove strange characters while using regex and xlrd module Python

Tags: python, regex, xlrd

I am trying to read the second column of an excel file using xlrd module. But the issue is the second column also has blank rows . I need to select only the values but not the rows . Below is my code for it:

```
import xlrd
import sys
import re

workbook_name = sys.argv[1]
if workbook_name:
    book = xlrd.open_workbook(workbook_name)
    for sheet in book.sheet_names():
        if re.search(r'Munich',sheet):
            sh = book.sheet_by_name(sheet)
            #num_cols = sh.ncols
            for row_ids in range(0,sh.nrows):
                cell_obj = str(sh.cell(row_ids,1))
                blank_regex = re.compile(r'u\'\'')
                if not re.search(blank_regex,cell_obj):
                    #re.sub('^.+u'()',\1,cell_obj)
                    print(cell_obj)
else:
    print ("Please supply workbook_name")
```

When i get the output , this is what i get :

```
text:u'Dom0'
text:u'muclgd0008.dedc2.cloud.com'
text:u'muclgd0007.dedc2.cloud.com'
text:u'muclgd0006.dedc2.cloud.com'
text:u'muclgd0005.dedc2.cloud.com'
text:u'muclgd0004.dedc2.cloud.com'
text:u'muclgd0003.dedc2.cloud.com'
text:u'Dom0'
text:u'muclmx0032.dedc2.cloud.com'
text:u'muclmx0031.dedc2.cloud.com'
text:u'muclmx0030.dedc2.cloud.com'
text:u'muclmx0029.dedc2.cloud.com'
text:u'muclmx0028.dedc2.cloud.com'
text:u'muclmx0027.dedc2.cloud.com'
text:u'muclmx0026.dedc2.cloud.com'
text:u'muclmx0025.dedc2.cloud.com'
text:u'muclgp0002.dedc2.cloud.com'
text:u'muclgp0001.dedc2.cloud.com'
text:u'Hardware Device'
text:u'Exadata X2-2 Quater Rack'
text:u'Exadata X2-2 Quater Rack'
text:u'ZFS Filer'
text:u'BDA'
```

I am not sure why this strange text:u'' is coming at the beginning.These characters are not there in the excel sheet.

Can someone please guide me on how to remove the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The "u" represents a Unicode string.

Comment: That's how the cell look like. You want the cell value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the `u` because you're using Python 2, and you're getting the quotes because you are printing out the "cell object" (which you implicitly convert to its "repr"), rather than its value. Use [`sh.cell_value()`](http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlrd.sheet.Sheet.cell_value) instead of `str(sh.cell())`.

Once you do that, you can just strip whitespace and check if the result is non-empty:

```
if cell_text.strip():
    print(cell_text)
```